# Выпадающее меню

Tags: jquery, css

Как сделать похожее меню?  szgoodlighting.com/gd/

Css вытащить у меня вышло, а вот как узнать js не знаю

http://ssmaker.ru/1845e2b0.jpg

Моя структура меню: http://ssmaker.ru/485b6649.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.menu ul>li').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
  }
);
```

```css
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.menu ul>li>ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: #acf;
}
.menu ul>li>ul>li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 3px;
}
.menu ul>li>ul>li:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">menu</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Lorem</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Amet</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Tempora</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Quos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Distinctio</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример на css

```css
nav {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul > li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul > li:hover a {
  color: #5DBDDC;
}
nav ul > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 250px;
  background: #5DBDDC;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 0 10px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s linear;
  transition: max-height 0.4s linear;
}
nav ul > li > ul > li{
  display: block;
}

nav ul > li:last-child > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
nav ul > li:hover ul {
  max-height: 200px;
}
nav ul > li:hover ul a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav class="clearfix">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Главная 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Главная 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Главная 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Главная 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">О нас</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Услуги</a> 
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Услуга 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Услуга 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Услуга 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Услуга 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ОБЪЕКТЫ</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">вопросы</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ДЛЯ ПОСТАВЩИКОВ</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ДЛЯ ПОСТАВЩИКОВ 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ДЛЯ ПОСТАВЩИКОВ 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ДЛЯ ПОСТАВЩИКОВ 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ДЛЯ ПОСТАВЩИКОВ 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял,то можно использовать такой принцип

```
  <div class="view-source">

  <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
  <div class="hide">
     MESSAGE OF CEO</br>
      COMPANY PROFILE

    </div>
</div>
```

затем с помощью jquery,обрабатываем нажатие на ссылку

```
$(function(){
    $('.view-source .hide').hide();
    $a = $('.view-source a');
    $a.on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $a.not(this).next().slideUp(500);
      $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Ну а дальше уже настроишь css и если что под себя поменяешь
вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/xmdz3d0a/2/

Comment: Нужно что бы было при наведении, а не клике